# Как двигать элементы в bootstrap?

Tags: bootstrap, flask

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сдвинуть форму вниз в bootstrap? Нагуглил только, как переместить вправо с помощью col-md-offset-* класса.

Comment: Изучите css....

Comment: `<nav class="navbar fixed-bottom">...</nav>`

Comment: `margin-top: NNpx; padding-top: NNpx;`

Answer (score 1):

1. Если вы используете 4-ый бутстрап, то там появились классы исключительно для отступов. Почитайте [spacing](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/). В третьем бутстрапе такого нет. Например, добавьте класс `.mt-5`.
2. Можете вручную прописать отступ для вашего блока, например `margin-top:50px;`
3. Самый не красивый, но рабочий вариант, если у вас нет возможности править css, то можете добавить несколько переносов строки: `<br>`